# How to replace NaN values in a column by existing Strings in the same column through putting a conditional statement on other column in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONHto.png

I have to replace NaN by appropriate Values of City, as we know by other rows that Cities C,F,D belong to States AB BC and DE respectively. I am currently coding on Python 3.8

[1]:

Comment: What file format is your dataframe in?

Comment: To help you we need a little more information
I assume you use pandas is that correct? Based on which condition do you want to fill the NaNs: e.g. Are the nans always at cities C, F, D or also for different cities?

Comment: It would be beneficial if you provided us with a sample of the data.  Please review Jon Skeet's excellent blog post [WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) for guidance in updating your question.  For a more detailed tutorial on asking a good question see Eric S. Raymond's site [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: Could u please provide your code, or a simplified version and maybe give us an input / output example?